# Extended Selberg class and RH

Tags: number-theory, l-functions

Is it known whether an element of the extended Selberg class that fulfills the analogue of the Riemann hypothesis actually belongs to the Selberg class ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The analogue of RH for the extended Selberg class is GRH? The only axiom needed in addition for Selberg class is the one concerning the Euler product, right?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by GRH ? By the way, there are known examples of elements of the extended Selberg class that do not fulfill the analogue of RH, like the Davenport-Heilbron L-function, but perhaps I misunderstood your comment. The Euler product requirement seems to be essential.

Comment: I mean "Grand Riemann hypothesis".

Comment: You fixed your comment while I was typing mine. The Ramanujan-Petersson requirement is needed too to define the Selberg class.

Comment: Ok. I don't know if it is known whether automorphic L-functions belong to the extended Selberg class, nor if it is known that elements thereof fulfilling the analogue of RH are automorphic.